# How to map Business layer to Model objects in UML?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, uml, staruml

Just started with `Star UML` to draw a `class diagram`.

As with any application, `MyBLL`(business layer) creates an instance of `Model` after interacting with the `DAO`(database layer).

More or less, the simplified (for clarity) class diagram looks like this:

[image]

It is obvious that the model class will no longer be used after BLL is done.

1. What should I use here? `aggregation` or `composition` while mapping `MyBLL` to `MyModel`.
2. I have used a `composition` relationship from `MyBLL` to `MyDAO`. My logic is after the `BLL` layer exists, `MyDAO` will no longer exist because it is referenced in `MyBLL`. Is this correct?

Note: This is for a `WebAPI` project that I am creating using C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Aggregate** means that the child CAN exist without the parent. So, `Classroom` (parent) and `Student` (child) is the most common example. Where you can have classrooms and students independently.

**Composite** means that the child CANNOT exist without the parent. So, `House` (parent) and `Room` (child) is the most common example. Where you cannot have a room without it being inside a house.

Without seeing exactly how you are coding this I am guessing that you will have this:

1) MyModel is probably a **composite** relationship because it is contained (with other models) within your MyBLL for its whole life. When MyBLL goes out of scope so too does MyModel.

2) MyDAO is probably an **aggregate** because it can exist without MyBLL as it is used by other components? I.e. It is probably created outside of your MyBLL by the host and injected into your BLL?

Both of these statements may not be true based on the actual way your have architected your system.

Comment: Clear and up to the point. Thanks. And with Point 2: `I am just referencing the DAO library, creating and using it within the BLL`. So, accordingly BLL to DAO should be composite right (with reference to my case` ?

Comment: In that case then yes they are both composite because the BLL is creating everything and without it nothing can exist. Whether that is what you actually want is another matter but at least it will be clear to see that BLL is owner / container of everything.

Comment: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#composition says "..When composition is used in domain models, both whole/part relationship as well as event of composite "deletion" should be interpreted figuratively, not necessarily as physical containment and/or termination.."